# What is a "processing node" on Dataproc?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

Dataproc [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/preemptible-vms) says that preemptible VMs are only attached as processing nodes. What is a processing node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a preemptible VM is used in Dataproc the preemptible VM will not be used as an HDFS DataNode. This is done primarily so that when the VM is preempted there will not be lost or under-replicated data.

Comment: I guess my question was not what the preemptive VM doesn't do, but what does it do?

Comment: Think of a preemptible VM as compute-only (Hadoop MR, spark, pig, whatever); they are not used for persistent storage.